# On iOS, Is there a way to get the size of an ImageContext after creating it using UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions?

Tags: ios, uikit, core-graphics, graphicscontext

If an image context is created using:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(768, 768), YES, 1.0);
```

is there a way to get the size of the context later on?  The size for sure is there when the image is obtained from the context, but while drawing, is there also a way to get the width and size of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a bitmap context as above you can use:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
size_t width = CGBitmapContextGetWidth(context);
size_t height = CGBitmapContextGetHeight(context);
```

Comment: works with ImageContext... and I guess supposedly it won't work with a context that is a CGLayer of size (768, 768)

Comment: (coz it would print out error even thought that CGLayer was created with a size (768, 768))

Comment: This exact code returns 0 for me (both for width and for height). I thought that's because the UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext doesn't return a bitmap context.